# ¿Como quitar el icono del reloj en el input type time?

Tags: html, css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De que forma se puede quitar ese relojito ?

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: puedes probar usar la herramienta de inspector , y buscar el id o class de dicho reloj y al sacarlo poder ocultarlo o eliminarlo tambien

Comment: @JuanCarlos ese ícono de reloj es propio del navegador, es decir el OP no lo puso y va a depender desde que navegador lo visualices que la apariencia cambie

Comment: @BetaM ok. Ya veo

Comment: Por lo que veo en firefox no se visualiza, tampoco tiene un id o algo por el estilo para cambiarlo con un css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta con que utilices lo siguiente:

```css
input[type="time"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<input type=" time" />
```